# Cannot create new list.phtml file on Custom Magento Theme

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog, product-list

I have copied list.phtml from Magento's rwd theme; however, no products load when I add it to my custom Magento theme. Does this happen when the original files have been edited?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I replaced /rwd and /base directories using [Mage Mirror](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror) and now I am able to upload a new list.phtml file to my Custom Theme.